# .equals method returns false despite of strings being same

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to do a palindrome program. I'm a beginner. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // palindrome

        System.out.println("Enter a statement");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = scan.nextLine();
        StringBuilder str;
        str = new StringBuilder(userInput.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().trim().toString());
        System.out.println(str);
        String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().trim();
        System.out.println(reversed);

        if(str.equals(reversed)){
            System.out.println("is palindrome");
        }else{
            System.out.println("not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried debugging mode and everything. Cant figure out why it returns not palindrome.

Answer (score 5):

`str` is a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`. `replaced` is a `String`. `StringBuilder.equals` will never return `true` when the operand isn't another `StringBuilder`.

Make `str` a `String` so you're using `String.equals` and comparing a string with another string.

Comment: StringBuilder str;
str = new StringBuilder(userInput.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().trim().toString());
so .tostring() which I mentioned in last is not converting it to String?

Comment: @Newbie - No, because you're feeding all of that into `new StringBuilder`, which creates a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`. Moreover, the fact it's a `StringBuilder` is made clear from the declaration `StringBuilder str`. You don't need a `StringBuilder` for this part at all: `String str = userInput.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().trim();`.

Comment: Demonstrates the importance of naming choices. 'str' is not a good name for a Stringbuilder instance.  I'm all in favour of concise naming for increased readability, so 'str' is fine for an actual String.  Maybe 'sb' for a Stringbuilder. (I adhere to the doctrine that short abbreviations are fine for local variables where you can see the declaration pretty close to use; members might need to be more descriptive)